# How to validate response with multiple inputs in karate

Tags: rest, karate

I am trying to validate the response by giving multiple inputs using Karate framework. Below is the sample feature file.

```
 Scenario Outline: response validation
    Given url 'urls?xyz=[<value>]'
    When method get
    Then status <status>
    And match response == [{abc:'<response>'},{pqr:'<response1>'}]

Examples:
      | value  | status | response | response1          |
      |      3 |    200 |        3 | null               |
      | *      |    400 |          | Invalid xyz        |
      |     65 |    200 |          |                    |
      | &^%^&% |    400 |          | Invalid xyz        |
```

But not able to validate both condition at a time, one of the parameter will always be null either 'abc' or 'pqr'. Below is the exception I am getting.

```
12:28:11.204 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - response time in milliseconds: 742
12:28:11.276 [pool-1-thread-1] ERROR c.i.k.cucumber.KarateJunitFormatter - failed feature: path.my
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.util.List
    at com.intuit.karate.Script.matchNestedObject(Script.java:969)
    at com.intuit.karate.Script.matchJsonPath(Script.java:871)
    at com.intuit.karate.Script.matchNamed(Script.java:597)
    at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.matchNamed(StepDefs.java:463)
    at com.intuit.karate.StepDefs.matchEquals(StepDefs.java:453)
    at ✽.And match response == [{abc:'3'},{pqr:''}](path/my.feature:27)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I recommend you go through this example once, it will give you a lot of ideas and has different approaches to solve this: [`dynamic-params.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/develop/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/search/dynamic-params.feature). For example you may want to use the `params` keyword instead of concatenating query params into the URL.

In my experience, it is simpler to place a JSON snippet in the `Examples:` table, something like this:

```
And match response == <expected>

Examples:
  | value  | status | expected                      |
  |      3 |    200 | [{abc:3},{pqr:null}]          |
  | *      |    400 | [{pqr:'Invalid xyz'}]         |
```